# How do I move a file in Android Studio and have its usages be updated with the new path?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, refactoring

I moved a file inside my `lib` folder from the `providers` folder to the `shared` folder. After doing so, every widget of mine that was referencing that file now has an error because it is still looking for that file in the original location. I even made sure to right click the file and hit "Refactor", yet this still happened. How do I move the file properly so that the usages get updated? I tried googling this but all I see are questions about moving entire projects.

Example widget that is erroring out:

```
import 'package:ats/providers/global_functions.dart'; //ERROR: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:ats/providers/global_functions.dart'. 
//...rest of code...
```

What should have happened is that the widget above should have updated its usage to this:

```
import 'package:ats/shared/global_functions.dart';
```

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/4279

Answer (score 0):

`Using refactor -> Move file` is for me the good solution, but sometimes caches is a problem. After refactoring the location you can try to `invalidate cache`.